# Problem to change an occurence in a file with sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a file with several lines :

```
OTU3055 UniRef90_A0A0F7KBB1 UniRef90_A0A1Z9IPT2
OTU0856 OTU53699 UniRef90_D6PC25 UniRef90_D6PCA5 UniRef90_D6PCG3
OTU0125 UniRef90_A0A075FUN0 UniRef90_A0A075G8Q1 UniRef90_A0A075GDT2
```

I want to remove all OTUXXXX occurences (there are always 4 numbers after the "OTU") which appears in the file. I used `sed` but it didn't work. The OTUXXXX always appearat the beginning of the lines.

`sed 's/OTU[0-9]{4} //g' my_file.txt`

I put a space after `OTU[0-9]{4}` because I want the Uniref90 IDs are at the beginning of eacg line.

Edit :

`sed -r 's/OTU[0-9]{4} //g' my_file.txt` works. But I get another problem,

```
UniRef90_A0A0F7KBB1 UniRef90_A0A1Z9IPT2
 UniRef90_D6PC25 UniRef90_D6PCA5 UniRef90_D6PCG3
UniRef90_A0A075FUN0 UniRef90_A0A075G8Q1 UniRef90_A0A075GDT2
```

Some lines still begin with a white space. I tried `sed 's/^ *//' my_file.txt` and it does not work. I want the second line of my file starts like the two other lines, without any space.

Comment: Add option `-r` to GNU sed.

Comment: or escape both curly brackets with a \.

Comment: I noticed that the previous command works but for some lines, the "blank space" at the beginning of some rows is not removed. It worked for some but not for others. Do you have an idea? I tried `sed 's/^ *//' my_file.txt` but nothing happens.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Using -r argument, I still get a leading OTU on line 2 (where there are two). If I take off the 'space' in the pattern, it works to find OTU's, but leaves a leading space.

Comment: I get  a different result - https://ideone.com/SZFTkG. Try `sed -r 's/[[:space:]]*\bOTU[0-9]{4,}\b[[:space:]]*//g' file`, check [this demo](https://ideone.com/gyzXcM).

Comment: `OTU53699` has 5 digits after the OTU, you said you wanted to remove OUT<4 digits> but your expected output shows it removed. Between that and the magic blank char, whether that has 5 digits or 4 it's simply not possible for the sed command you posted to produce the output you posted from the input you posted. There's something you aren't telling us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
sed -r 's/[[:space:]]*\bOTU[0-9]{4,}\b[[:space:]]*//g' file > newfile
```

Or, if the matches can be found anywhere, not only at the string start:

```
sed -r 's/[[:space:]]*\bOTU[0-9]{4,}\b//g' file | sed 's/[[:space:]]*$//' > newfile
```

The whitespaces after the `OTU<digits>` won't get matched with the second snippet, so a piped `sed` command is necessary.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/gyzXcM).

**Details**

- `[[:space:]]*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `\b`  a word boundary
- `OTU[0-9]{4,}` - `OTU` and 4 or more digits
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[[:space:]]*` -  0+ whitespace chars.

Comment: If you use `-E` instead of `-r` then it'll work in both GNU and OSX/BSD sed instead of just GNU sed.

Comment: @EdMorton Yes, true.

Answer (score 0):

There is no explanation for your posted actual output given your posted input and the command you ran but if you want to match on 4 or more digits and the space after the OTU* strings could be a tab or some other white space that's not a blank char then this is what you need using GNU or OSX/BSD awk for `-E`:

```
$ sed -E 's/(OTU[0-9]{4,}[[:space:]]+)+//' file
UniRef90_A0A0F7KBB1 UniRef90_A0A1Z9IPT2
UniRef90_D6PC25 UniRef90_D6PCA5 UniRef90_D6PCG3
UniRef90_A0A075FUN0 UniRef90_A0A075G8Q1 UniRef90_A0A075GDT2
```